# Position: absolute with overflow-y: scroll Scroll doesn't reach the top of the object

Tags: css, scroll, css-position, overflow, absolute

So I recently launched my first site! The thing that gave me the biggest headache was this little scroll on the left side of the main page not reaching the top, making the first items impossible to read.

The site is on https://divot.now.sh . All the code is there. I would also appreciate any feedback about design, functionality and security since it's my first website and I'm trying to learn the most out of it.

Comment: Looks like you have to use `top` property to get it fixed, if you share the HTML and CSS code then we can take a peek at it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `display: inline-block;` to your #boxes section:

```
    #boxes{
       display: inline-block;
    }
```

Comment: You sir are the best. Why is that inline-block prevents it from going up?